# tf.keras ImageDataGenerator for Semantic Segmentation: Keep y values as integers

Tags: python-3.x, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, image-preprocessing

**In short**

I want to use the easy to use `tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator` to load batches of `X` and `y` images to train CNNs for semantic segmentation. Augmentation is to be applied on the fly.

Unfortunately, the values of the `y` images are altered in the process, which should not be, since those values are integers that encode classes.

**The data and the code I use so far**

I have `X` and `y` data, which are both images in `.tif` format:

- `X` images are RGB images with the dimensions 128 x 128 x 3 (3 colour bands), and with values in `dtype=uint8`, theoretically in a range from 0 to 255.
- `y` images are single band (grayscale) images with the dimensions 128 x 128 x 1 and `dtype=uint8`. They encode 33 classes as integers.

I set up `ImageDataGenerator`s to load those images in batches:

```
args_col = {"data_format" : "channels_last",
            "featurewise_std_normalization" : False,
            "brightness_range" : [0.5, 1.5]
            }
args_aug = {"rotation_range" : 365,
            "width_shift_range" : 0.25,
            "height_shift_range" : 0.25,
            "horizontal_flip" : True,
            "vertical_flip" : True,
            "fill_mode" : "constant",
            "featurewise_center" : False
            }
args_flow = {"class_mode" : None,
             "batch_size" : 10,
             "target_size" : (128, 128),
             "seed" : 42
             }

X_generator = ks.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1.0/255.0,
                                                        **args_aug,
                                                        **args_col)
X_gen = X_generator.flow_from_directory(directory = "/path/to/X",
                        color_mode = "rgb",
                        **args_flow)

y_generator = ks.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(**args_aug,
                                                        cval = NoDataValue,
                                                        dtype = "uint8")
y_gen = y_generator.flow_from_directory(directory = "/path/to/y",
                        color_mode = "grayscale",
                        interpolation = "nearest",
                        **args_flow)

train_generator = zip(X_gen, y_gen)
```

As you can see, I set a `seed` value, in order to get matching pairs of images and masks. The `X` images are rescaled and their brightness is altered, which is not the case for the `y` images.

The output looks like this:

[image: ImageDataGenerator output]

So the tiles are matching and everything looks fine at first glance. However, when I load a pair of images and look at the data format (by running the following code), I'll get `dtype=float32`:

```
sample_image, sample_mask = next(train_generator)

sample_mask
```

This is despite I set `dtype = "uint8"` for the `y` generator. What is even worse: Not only the data type has changed, but the values are even altered:

```
mask_array = np.array(sample_mask)
np.unique(mask_array)
```

returns:

```
Out[218]: 
array([ 3.       ,  3.0429225,  3.0458798, ..., 31.99783  , 31.999964 ,
       32.       ], dtype=float32)
```

(Note the figures following the decimal delimiter!)

Obviously, there must have been some kind of interpolation when rotating the images. I set the `interpolation` in the `.flow_from_directory` part to `"nearest"` because I thought this would resolve the problem and choose the pixel values of the output using the *nearest neighbor* method. Unfortunately, this is not the case (at least at some point, there is interpolation going on and my integer classes are averaged).

So, how do I prevent this? I would like to continue using the `ImageDataGenerator` if possible, since it keeps the code easy to read.

**Edit:**

I also tried using `preprocessing_function = toINT` with a function

```
def toINT(filename):
    imgINT = filename.astype("uint8")
    return imgINT
```

which, however, also didn't work. Probably the values are changed to float somewhere at the end of the preprocessing...

Comment: Were you able to fix this somehow? I'm facing the same: the rotation interpolates the labels...

Comment: Unfortunately not; I am currently using an other ImageDataGenerator and only rotate by 90 and 180 degrees...

Answer (score 0):

You Should encode the mask before proceeding to model training